# SSRS Report Emails will not Send

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to set up my SSRS 2012 subscriptions and though I have used all the same details as I use in Database Mail I cannot get it to send out emails but I am not getting any error messages from the job.

The only difference I can see is under the Database Mail Configuration Wizard there is listed SMTP Authentication "Basic Authentication" details, are these needed to be put in the RSreportsever.config file and if so where??

Thanks Phil

Comment: Take a look at the status column in the table ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the response, I have taken a look at the table that you suggested but there is only one field with Status as part of the name and that is "LastStatus", in here it is only saying "New Subscription" but nothing else, does this mean anything to yourself besides that its a New Subscription, Thanks Phil

Comment: Hi Jason, if its of any further help, I have just looked in the ExecutionLog table in the reporting database and for the emails that I am sending out it says "rsSuccess" under Status, is this where you meant for me to look.  Thanks P

Answer (score 1):

SSRS can't do basic authentication like the SQL/Database Mail can. There is an article about setting up a virtual local SMTP service that SSRS can send.  This virtual SMTP then forwards your emails to the real SMTP server-- which can use basic authentication. http://en.sql4you.info/?p=132